# Navbar stacked under one another and also not aligned as desired

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

So, I'm just starting with web dev and was learning bootstrap. This is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IMAGE GALLERY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .navcolor{
            background-color: #042638;
        }   
        .textcolor{
            color: white;
        }
        .align{
            margin-left: 80px;
        }
        .one{
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            color:white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class=" navbar navabar-default navcolor ">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <img class="one align" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/212-2129758_ios-gallery-icon-png.png" >
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand textcolor ">IMGS</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
            <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I should have a separate file for CSS, but I was just trying something. Now, this definitely seems very basic. I was expecting something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Sj9.jpg).
But, what I got was, [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjcSg.jpg).
Ignore the logo ofc. I'm more concerned about the fact that 'About' and 'Contact' are stacked over one other and also for some reason it is in the middle. I tried 'navbar-left' or 'pull-left' but it stays in the middle. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can place `About` and `Contact` next to each other using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

As for bringing the links from the middle to the left, I'd recommend placing them in a new `<div>` and utilising flexbox with `justify-content`:

```
.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

As is done in this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>IMAGE GALLERY</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .navcolor {
      background-color: #042638;
    }
    
    .textcolor {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .one {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .links {
      flex-grow: 1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class=" navbar navabar-default navcolor ">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img class="one align" src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/212-2129758_ios-gallery-icon-png.png">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand textcolor ">IMGS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
        <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a class="textcolor" href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```